# Attaching external attachment to Testrail in playwright C#

Tags: c#, playwright, testrail

I have a trace file from playwright that I would like to attach to my testrail testcase as an external attachment from a know path.

I'm using the testrail trcli once the report is created its using `nunit3-junit.xslt` to transform the report which then parsed to testrail

I have included in my code:

```
TestContext.AddTestAttachment("Pathfile", "This is my attachment");
```

I can see the file in my `report.XML` but once I run the `trcli` its not attaching.

I'm now assuming that that the  `nunit3-junit.xslt` is not mapped to handle this.

I'm not sure what this should look like

Comment: You might want to have a look at the commercial TR integration platform names [Railflow](https://railflow.io). It support Playwright native reports out of the box. See the example here: https://docs.railflow.io/docs/railflow-for-testrail/playwright